# Xamarin Forms ListView, When TranslateTo Animation Hide By other Items

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I intended to coding" when Listview items appearing and Items appearing " items appearing from **top** or **bottom**. ( using TranslateTo )

but When Listview Viewcell Appearing, or itemsAppearing, i tried to Apply animations.
but, higher index of items hiding lower index of items animation.
so, lower index items animation is only show shortly. ( cropped by other layout)

[Please Check Image Description _ Animation Cropped by items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SSkI.png)

in Xamarin Forms(C#)

```
    private async void ItemsListView_ItemAppearing_1(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
    
        int i = e.ItemIndex;
        int y;

        y = 400;
        for (int d = 0; d < i; d++)
        {
            int z = d + 1;
            y = y + (400 / (z * z));
        }

        uint x = uint.Parse(y.ToString());

        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> pInfos = (ItemsListView as ItemsView<Cell>).GetType().GetRuntimeProperties();
        var templatedItems = pInfos.FirstOrDefault(info => info.Name == "TemplatedItems");
        if (templatedItems != null)
        {
            var cells = templatedItems.GetValue(ItemsListView);
            var cell = (cells as Xamarin.Forms.ITemplatedItemsList<Xamarin.Forms.Cell>)[e.ItemIndex] as ViewCell;

          //cell.View.Opacity = 0;
            cell.View.TranslationY = Var.Device_Height / Var.Device_Scale;
          await  cell.View.TranslateTo(0, 0, x, Easing.CubicOut);


        }
    }
```

In XAML

```
     <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" BackgroundColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="Fill"         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  Margin="0" SeparatorVisibility="None" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" 
                              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" HasUnevenRows="True"  IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" ItemAppearing="ItemsListView_ItemAppearing_1"
                             >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell Appearing="ViewCell_Appearing">       
                                    <ViewCell.View>

                                        <Frame IsClippedToBounds="False" 
                                               Margin="0,5" 
                                               CornerRadius="10" 
                                               Padding="0" 
                                               HasShadow="False" 
                                               BorderColor="#f0f0f0" 
                                               BackgroundColor="Transparent" >
 
                                    <StackLayout Padding="0" Spacing="0" MinimumHeightRequest="0">
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="13,12,5,0" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" TextColor="#222222">
                                                       
                                                    </Label>
                                                    <Frame MinimumHeightRequest="0" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="7,2,7,2" CornerRadius="100" BackgroundColor="Accent" HasShadow="False">
                                                     
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Sequence}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Micro"/>
                                                    </Frame>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Mail}" Margin="13,6,0,12">                        
                                                </Label>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                                                        </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

it is same result, when **ViewCell_appearing** or **items_Appearing**

Comment: I slow down your animation, here is running GIF. https://imgur.com/a/KFQIZ6Y, I set your code in the `ViewCell_Appearing`, the higher index of items not hide lower index of items animation

Comment: And I do not know what is your value set for `Var.Device_Height / Var.Device_Scale;` So, I set the value for testing. `public static double Device_Height = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;` and `public static double Device_Scale = 6;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my background code for TranslateTo Animation Hide By other Items.

```
 public static double Device_Height = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;

        public static double Device_Scale = 6;
        int i;
        private async void mylistview_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
        {
             i = e.ItemIndex;
           
        }

        private async void ViewCell_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //  int i = e.ItemIndex;
            int y;

            y = 4000;
            for (int d = 0; d < i; d++)
            {
                int z = d + 1;
                y = y + (400 / (z * z));
            }

            uint x = uint.Parse(y.ToString());
            var cell = sender as ViewCell;
            cell.View.TranslationY = Device_Height / Device_Scale;
            await cell.View.TranslateTo(0, 0, x, Easing.CubicOut);
        }
```

Here is running GIF(I slow down your animation).

[image]

I upload my demo to you, you can test it.

https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/MyCusListview.zip

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: Thanks for your Answering,sincerly. Because of holiday, I just checked.

Comment: I Tested your code, sample works the same as my code.

Comment: I want the animation (TranslationY ) not to be clipped by other layout items.if ScrollDown, items appearing form top. and Scrolling up, appearing from down, the user can see items from layout's(Listview) bottom or top. but demo just appearing from it's cell

Comment: Because we add the animation to the viewcell, so the item appearing from it's cell, it you want to make the part of disappeared items from top. This way cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

To reply on @Leon Lu :Yes there is a way.
You could check if the integer i == 0.

```
public static double Device_Height = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;

    public static double Device_Scale = 6;
    int i;
    private async void mylistview_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
         i = e.ItemIndex;
    }

    private async void ViewCell_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            int y;
            y = 4000;
            for (int d = 0; d < i; d++)
            {
                int z = d + 1;
                y = y + (400 / (z * z));
            }

            uint x = uint.Parse(y.ToString());
            var cell = sender as ViewCell;
            cell.View.TranslationY = Device_Height / Device_Scale;
            await cell.View.TranslateTo(0, 0, x, Easing.CubicOut);
        }
    }
```

But unfortunally now it animates only the second row. But I'm looking for an solution!
I think, in my case, it has something to do with the ListView population through the Binding..